# Expression tree for child collection List<string>.Any

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I am building generic linq query using expression tree. I am stuck when creating expression on child collection. Method call blows up because of incompatible types. Normally I know what to put there, but the Any() method call has me confused. I've tried every type I can think of and no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my entity class:

```
public class Story : Entity
{
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public IList<string> Contributors { get; set; }
}
```

Query for which I want to generate expression tree:

```
var stories = new List<Story>();
stories.Where(p => p.Author.Contains("Test") || p.Contributors.Any(c => c.Contains("Test")));
```

What I have got so far

```
public interface IFilterCriteria
{
    string PropertyToCompare { get; set; }
    object ValueToCompare { get; set; }
    FilterOperator FilterOperator { get; set; }
    bool IsList { get; set; }
    Expression Expression { get; set; }
}

public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, IList<IFilterCriteria> filterCriterias, LogicalOperator logicalOperator = LogicalOperator.And)
{
    if (filterCriterias != null && filterCriterias.Any())
    {
        var resultCondition = filterCriterias.ToExpression(query, logicalOperator);

        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "p");

        if (resultCondition != null)
        {
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda(resultCondition, parameter);

            var mce = Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable), "Where",
                new[] { query.ElementType },
                query.Expression,
                lambda);

            return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(mce);
        }
    }
    return query;
}

public static Expression ToExpression<T>(this IList<IFilterCriteria> filterCriterias, IQueryable<T> query, LogicalOperator logicalOperator = LogicalOperator.And)
{
    Expression resultCondition = null;
    if (filterCriterias.Any())
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "p");

        foreach (var filterCriteria in filterCriterias)
        {
            var propertyExpression = filterCriteria.PropertyToCompare.Split('.').Aggregate<string, MemberExpression>(null, (current, property) => Expression.Property(current ?? (parameter as Expression), property));

            Expression valueExpression;
            var constantExpression = Expression.Constant(filterCriteria.ValueToCompare);

            if (!filterCriteria.IsList)
            {
                valueExpression = Expression.Convert(constantExpression, propertyExpression.Type);
            }
            else
            {
                valueExpression = Expression.Call(typeof (Enumerable), "Any", new[] {typeof (string)},
                                                  propertyExpression, filterCriteria.Expression,
                                                  Expression.Constant(filterCriteria.ValueToCompare,
                                                                      typeof (string)));
            }

            Expression condition;
            switch (filterCriteria.FilterOperator)
            {
                case FilterOperator.IsEqualTo:
                    condition = Expression.Equal(propertyExpression, valueExpression);
                    break;
                case FilterOperator.IsNotEqualTo:
                    condition = Expression.NotEqual(propertyExpression, valueExpression);
                    break;
                case FilterOperator.IsGreaterThan:
                    condition = Expression.GreaterThan(propertyExpression, valueExpression);
                    break;
                case FilterOperator.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo:
                    condition = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(propertyExpression, valueExpression);
                    break;
                case FilterOperator.IsLessThan:
                    condition = Expression.LessThan(propertyExpression, valueExpression);
                    break;
                case FilterOperator.IsLessThanOrEqualTo:
                    condition = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(propertyExpression, valueExpression);
                    break;
                case FilterOperator.Contains:
                    condition = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) }), valueExpression);
                    break;
                case FilterOperator.StartsWith:
                    condition = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) }), valueExpression);
                    break;
                case FilterOperator.EndsWith:
                    condition = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith", new[] { typeof(string) }), valueExpression);
                    break;
                default:
                    condition = valueExpression;
                    break;
            }

            if (resultCondition != null)
            {
                switch (logicalOperator)
                {
                    case LogicalOperator.And:
                        resultCondition = Expression.AndAlso(resultCondition, condition);
                        break;
                    case LogicalOperator.Or:
                        resultCondition = Expression.OrElse(resultCondition, condition);
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                resultCondition = condition;
            }
        }
    }
    return resultCondition;
}
```

That's how I am using expressions:

```
var stories = new List<Story>();
var filters = new List<FilterCriteria>();
filter.Add(new FilterCriteria { ValueToCompare = "Test", PropertyToCompare = "Author", FilterOperator = FilterOperator.Contains });

Expression<Func<string, bool>> func  = t => t.Contains("Test");

filter.Add(new FilterCriteria { ValueToCompare = "Test", PropertyToCompare = "Contributors", FilterOperator = FilterOperator.Contains, Expression = func });

stories.Filter(filters, LogicalOperator.Or).ToList();
```

But after running this code, I get this error which I am not able to resolve

> No generic method 'Any' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible
>   with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments
>   should be provided if the method is non-generic.  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: No generic method
>   'Any' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied
>   type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if
>   the method is non-generic.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 184:                        { Line 185:
>   var overload = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Single(mi => mi.Name ==
>   "Any" && mi.GetParameters().Count() == 2); Line 186:
>   Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Any", new[] { typeof(string) },
>   propertyExpression, or); Line 187:
>   valueExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new[] {
>   typeof(string)}, propertyExpression, or, Expression.Constant("Test",

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't call `Any` method anywhere in your code.

You should extend `Contains`, example:

```
case FilterOperator.Contains:
    // if collection
    if (propertyExpression.Type.IsGenericType &&
        typeof(IEnumerable<>)
            .MakeGenericType(propertyExpression.Type.GetGenericArguments())
            .IsAssignableFrom(propertyExpression.Type))
    {
        // find AsQueryable method
        var toQueryable = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
            .Where(m => m.Name == "AsQueryable")
            .Single(m => m.IsGenericMethod)
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));

        // find Any method
        var method = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
            .Where(m => m.Name == "Any")
            .Single(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));

        // make expression
        condition = Expression.Call(
            null, 
            method,
            Expression.Call(null, toQueryable, propertyExpression), 
            filterCriteria.Expression
        );
    }
    else
    {
        condition = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) }), valueExpression);
    }
    break;
```

Also you should have created one `p` parameter (`Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "p")`) otherwise you'll get `variable 'p' of type 'WpfApplication2.Story' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined` error.

You may pass `parameter` from `Filter` method to `ToExpression` method.

Comment: Thanks Lolo, it worked as I expected, could you please suggest any good book or reference for furthering reading on Expression Tree.

Comment: @mgarg Not really, I haven't read anything about Expressions, I'd say I am self-taught. This site is my first source of information :)