# Build generic expression tree for filtering multiple property of child collection property

Tags: c#, generics, expression-trees

Lets take this example class

```
public class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        this.Items = new List<Item>();
    }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
public class Item{
    public decimal Cost{get;set;}
    public string ItemCode{get;set;}
}
```

I want to write a **generic** expression tree(should not specify any hard coded property name) where I can write multiple filter on single item above which is a **collection**.

**Example**

```
var selected = order.Items.Any(i => i.ItemCode == "MM" && i.Cost > 10);
```

Query has to on same item. Normally when we do AND operation it evaluate tree again on List of items, I need the query to be on the same item.

This type of Expression Tree I would like to right. This is just one example.

```
Expression propExpression = null;
Type propType = null;

ExpressionType tBinary;

propExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, r.MemberName);
propType = propExpression.Type;           


return Expression.Call(
    typeof(Regex).GetMethod("IsMatch",
        new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(RegexOptions) }),
    propExpression,
    Expression.Constant(r.TargetValue, typeof(string)),
    Expression.Constant(RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, typeof(RegexOptions))
);
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. The example does exactly what you ask (the way it's formulated currently).

Comment: I want to build generic expression tree. This is Lambda expression example.

Comment: Then provide an example of what do you mean by *to build* and *generic expression tree*.  Because the sample lambda expression *is* a generic expression tree *built* by the C# compiler. Are you asking how to compose predicate expression dynamically (e.g. some sort of a predicate builder)?

Comment: Updated original question with small example. Also Here is what I am trying achieve for collection.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748478/expression-tree-for-child-collection-liststring-any